# DOM node Coordinate while HTML rendering

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, dom

I use Chrome and http://www.aaai.org/Conferences/AAAI/aaai13.php for test.

There is a structure like that.

```
<div class="content">
<div class="right">...</div>
<div class="left">...</div>
</div>
```

I just have no idea about why the "content" div's size is 940px * 70px which is much smaller than the size of the "right" div and the "left" div.

Sorry for not knowing how to screenshot for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements which are floating doesn't use vertical space without clear. You can add empty element with "clear: both"-css to use that vertical space.

See more info from here:

[What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer is right.I have tried that if I put <div style="clear:both"></div> then the size of content is bigger than its children nodes.